# Find all non unicode characters in file

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

So i have a textfile that includes non unicode characters.
For example

```
"pr�s-*"
ESt Präs
```

How do I print them out, but only them. I know this java method for replacing it

```
String resultString = currentLine.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
```

I dont want to replace them, I want to find them and print it out.

Comment: You can use a `Matcher#find` with your regex. Or use `\P{ASCII}` regex - see http://ideone.com/jezqeN

Comment: Could you explain a better what you mean by non-Unicode chars? I thought all chars in Java were Unicode?

Comment: @OleV.V. Indeed. Flip, "non-Unicode" is a very strange construction. Although there are some "computer-stored" characters that are not yet in the Unicode character set, the whole concept of Unicode is to be, for all practical purposes, universal. In any case, characters in the Java string datatype are Unicode. Perhaps you mean characters that are also in some other specific character set. In that case, please state what that character set is. Or, do you mean characters that are in Unicode and at least one other character set? If so, please give a list of all character sets under consideration

Comment: The replacement character (black rhombus with the question mark in the center) is often shown by a text editor if corresponding bytes in the string are not valid in the encoding scheme (like UTF-8) used. If you work with a text copied from such an editor, you may want to find only the repl. character, which has the Unicode code point of U+FFFD. If you want to work with the original text, where you get some of the bytes displayed as the repl. char, than of course it's more complicated - you probably should at 1st find out what the correct encoding is (where those bytes really mean something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a `Matcher#find` to find and print all these non-ASCII chars with your `[^\\x00-\\x7F]` regex or `\\P{ASCII}`:

```
String s = "pr�s-*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\P{ASCII}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/jezqeN)

See [Java regex reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> `\p{ASCII}` = All ASCII:`[\x00-\x7F]`

And `\P` means a reverse class, all chars other than ASCII.